# Why am I getting an error that a file in Firebase Storage doesn't exist but it actually does when you follow the link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am saving a file to firebase storage and the file exits but I am getting error that it doesn't. I am obfuscating the URL and file so nobody here can see it. but it exists.

Yes it is the correct URL.

Here is the upload code.

```
async function uploadFile() {
    console.log('starting UPLOAD ========');
    const blob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then((r) => r.blob());
    var id = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log(` the unique id for the url is ----> ${id}`);
    const path = `/recordings/${id}`;
    setCopied(true);
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(path)
      .put(blob)
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded complete');
      });

    await storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(setURL);
  }
```

ERROR:

```
GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/burcmce.appspot.com/o/recordings%2Fbbf9217d3a36c6 404
XhrConnection.send @ connection.ts:75
doTheRequest @ request.ts:135
(anonymous) @ backoff.ts:63
setTimeout (async)
callWithDelay @ backoff.ts:61
start @ backoff.ts:115
NetworkRequest.start_ @ request.ts:205
(anonymous) @ request.ts:102
NetworkRequest @ request.ts:99
makeRequest @ request.ts:309
StorageService._makeRequest @ service.ts:296
(anonymous) @ service.ts:324
step @ tslib.es6.js:102
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:83
fulfilled @ tslib.es6.js:73
Promise.then (async)
step @ tslib.es6.js:75
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:76
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.js:72
StorageService.makeRequestWithTokens @ service.ts:316
(anonymous) @ reference.ts:368
step @ tslib.es6.js:102
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:83
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:76
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.js:72
getDownloadURL$1 @ reference.ts:361
getDownloadURL @ api.ts:232
ReferenceCompat.getDownloadURL @ reference.ts:219
uploadFile @ ProductScreen.js:461
async function (async)
uploadFile @ ProductScreen.js:447
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
ProductScreen.js:462 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'recordings/bbf9217d3a3aa999536c6' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}
```

Anyone having this issue. Here is the solution:

```
firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(path)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(function (downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        setURL(downloadURL);
      });

    // storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(setURL()); <<- not this.
```

Comment: How do we know you have the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to access a download URL before the file is fully uploaded.  Since you're using async/await, you can simply await the promise returned by the Firebase Storage SDK before trying to access its download.

In general, you are not using async/await idiomatically.  Here is a corrected version.  It's not a good idea to mix calls to `then` and `catch` with async/await.  Just use async/await throughout for a more natural expression.

```
async function uploadFile() {
    console.log('starting UPLOAD ========');
    const blob = (await fetch(mediaBlobUrl)).blob()
    var id = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log(` the unique id for the url is ----> ${id}`);
    const path = `/recordings/${id}`;
    setCopied(true);
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref(path)
    await ref.put(blob)
    console.log('Uploaded complete');

    const downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    setUrl(downloadUrl);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(path)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(function (downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        setURL(downloadURL);
      });

    // storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(setURL()); <<-- not this.
```